# How change php code to show the text?

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

This is the original code

```
        // the email address
        if ( isset( $this->stored_settings[ 'email' ] ) and '' != $this->stored_settings[ 'email' ] ) {
            $link_href = antispambot( esc_html( $this->stored_settings[ 'email' ] ) );
            if ( isset( $this->stored_settings[ 'email_text' ] ) and '' != $this->stored_settings[ 'email_text' ] ) {
                $link_text = $this->stored_settings[ 'email_text' ];
            } else {
                $link_text = $link_href;
            }
            $contact_list[] = sprintf(
                '<li id="scb-email"><a href="mailto:%s"><img src="%sassets/images/email_%s.svg" width="%d" height="%d" alt="%s" /><span>%s</span></a></li>',
                $link_href,
                $this->plugin_root_url,
                $this->current_icon_type,
                $this->current_icon_size,
                $this->current_icon_size,
                __( 'E-Mail', $this->plugin_slug ),
                esc_html( $link_text )
            );
        }
```

I changed code in this line to this:

```
<li id="scb-email"><i class="fa fa-envelope"><a href="mailto:%s"></a></i></li>
```

Can you someone told me, what I must put into the **a tags** for showing text of email?

Answer (score 1):

The `sprintf()` call must be modified.  Each `%s` is a placeholder for the later arguments, e.g. `$link_href`, `$this->plugin_root_url`, etc.  The old code line has 7 `%s`'s and thus the call has 8 arguments (1 string and 7 other arguments to put into the placeholders).  Your new line only contains one `%s` so far, so `sprintf()` will only get two passed variables, namely your new line and `$link_href`.

Now you want the email inside the `<a>` tags, so you must put another `%s` within those tags and add another argument to `sprintf()`'s function call.

Then end result should look like this:

```
$contact_list[] = sprintf(
            '<li id="scb-email"><i class="fa fa-envelope"><a href="mailto:%s">%s</a></i></li>',
            $link_href,
            $link_href
        );
```

The last argument could be swapped for `esc_html( $link_text )` if you want what the old code put between `<span>` tags.

Comment: Got it! Thank you for great explanation :-)